# FuelSDK: Updating Subscriber doesn't work

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I have to do following things when I create a subscriber

1. Create a subscriber with status - 'Unsubscribed' in the Business unit
2. Update an attribute 'ReferenceId' of the subscriber
3. Update the lists of the subscriber
4. Send a verification email through TriggerSend

All the above actions have to be performed separately but will be performed in the same sequence.

Now here is the problem that I am facing:

I am able to create the subscriber successfully but then:

1. If I update the attribute first then trigger doesn't work.
2. If I update the lists of the subscriber first then attribute updation doesn't happen.

**Note** In above problems I am getting success response every time I am sending the API request.

I am using FuelSDK Ruby agent and have been referring the documentation given [here](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/index.html)

Comment: I find this post a little confusing, and so I looked up what you at least mentioned in your last sentence.

I just realized that the guys at [fuel sdk](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/index.html) are referencing this forum, and especially the "marketing-cloud" tag as their domain.

It's perhaps ok to discuss all things FuelSDK here, but at least give it a unique tag or ask your users to prefix any question with "FuelSDK".

Preferably, FuelSDK goes far beyond Salesforce topics, so not sure this should be discussed in this StackExchange at all.